# How to send, get, exchange data between WiFi MCU (ESP8266, ESP32) and PC using WiFi dongle?

Tags: c#, .net, wifi, esp8266, esp32

I have

- MCU like ESP8266, ESP32.
- PC + WiFi dongle.

I want to send data between PC and MCU wireless and without any addition hardware (routers, bridges, dedicated-home-automation-servers, itc).

I hope there is some lightweight **ready to use .net** library to talk via WiFi probably UDP or Websockets, depending of what is **faster and have minimal latency**.

like

```
send(&myStruct)
```

..

```
struct=getData()
```

I know how to connect them using (ESP-web server + PC browser) or  (ESP-link + virtual COM).

But
I don't need or want to use web-browser based solutions, including Electron wrapper, MQTT, ESP-link, other bloatware.

*Not sure it is better to ask in arduino.stackexchange or electronics or stackowerflow.*

Comment: You consider MQTT "bloatware" but don't already know the answer to the question you're asking?

Comment: Usually I use lightweight protocols with minimal or zero overhead. I don't know why need to have  "brokers",  "publish/subscribe", itc in case I need only connect 2 devices.

Comment: There are different version of the WIFI standard and connection should work if the version are compatible,  I assume you have a machine with a WIFI interface and you should be able to communicate if the IP and Mask and masks are setup properly.  Routing will use standard IP routing.

Comment: Yes, connection works, but 2 solutions that I found are not good: one need Web-browser to make HTTP request (and have latency 50+ms @ESP8266), second need to install ESP-link software and virtual tcp-to-Serial software to PC and maintain both. This is unacceptable.

Comment: start SoftAP on esp8266, connect the PC to this AP, start a TCP server on PC or on esp8266, connect to this server with a TCP socket from the client side and send data both ways

Comment: @Juraj +1 would have proposed the same given the constraints. However, it's hard to imagine the PC isn't connected to some WiFi already.

Comment: Thank you. I am looking for ready to use project or library. If none will found - I will write based on Tarmo links.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're willing to put in the work and accept the risks (no guaranteed delivery or packet order), then UDP is probably the fastest, lowest-latency protocol choice available to you. The sensible architecture would be the PC as server and ESP as client (assuming the PC is the central hub where all your ESPs "connect" to). There are tons of tutorials available both [in C](https://www.binarytides.com/programming-udp-sockets-c-linux/) (for the ESP or PC) and [.Net](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/using-udp-services) (PC only) - you'll have to put them together for your solution.